# Admin Login is not redirecting to the dashboard after server change

Tags: login, admin-panel

I just moved my magento store from sharing server to AWS. After that I am not able to login as admin. Admin login page shows validation with wrong credentials and for right ones it refreshes the page with new url but stays in login page.

> The frontend works correctly.

Any leads?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using memcache?

Comment: It is not used.

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.
Its because of the php version in the server. Magento version 1.9 and in server, PHP version was 7. I changed the PHP version to 5.6 then the problem got fixed.

**The cause of the problem can be different and for me it was the PHP version in the server.**

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini update enable max_input_vars and increase the value

;How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 35000

that maybe can solve the issue.